# Can you really run your vs 2012 app on Win XP? and how?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've seen a lot of thread(s) regarding with their visual studio 2012 app to run with their Win XP-32bit. Some says you need to change your target framework to 4.0 below, install the same framework to target pc, then make sure you include your publish-prerequisite to your target framework.. but it doesn't work on my case ,it always says that my app is not a valid win32 etc.
my last resort would be compiling my vs 2012 app to vs 2010 but i dont think it's a good idea though.

Comment: For C++, you use the ``v110_xp`` Platform Toolset. The Windows 8.x SDK does not actually support targeting Windows XP, so this toolset ends up using the Windows 7.1A SDK. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) for some additional implications.

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to include that im using c# window based app.

Comment: Is the error coming from a ClickOnce setup or your exe? See [Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/10/15/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx). Also, what VS Update do you have installed?

Comment: yes it is. based on the link you've given..i just need to patchVisual Studio 2012 Update 1 CTP 3? i'll try it thanks.

Comment: https://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766831/visual-studio-2012-update-1-ctp-3-install-has-destroyed-ability-to-load-or-create-any-project

im afraid to continue this solution

Comment: [VS 2012 Update 4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301713) is the latest one. Try that. There was a regression in the Update 2 release for the Windows XP support which was fixed in Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

temporary solution:
for future reference(if the update solution dont work for your case):

1. build your window app(c#) to framework 4.0,
2. copy the files on your Debug Folder and paste on target pc
3. Run the .exe
4. Voila!